# XNA Using velocity

Tags: xna, c#, movement

Previously when making games I have just been using a Vector2 as the sprites position and altering that for movement, i.e.:

```
if(right key pressed)
   Position.X += movementspeed * gametime...;
```

However I now have the need to use a velocity vector for movement. So far what i'm doing is:

```
if(right key pressed)
   Velocity.X = movementspeed * gametime...;
...
Position += Velocity;
Velocity = Vector2.Zero; // Set velocity to 0
```

Is this how Velocity is implemented? I.e. setting it to a zero vector after each call of update?

Many thanks

Edit: When I stop pressing the key the sprite must stop moving, hence setting the velocity to zero.

Comment: If it's only moving when the button is pressed, it's not really velocity.  It's just a one-time position change.  Having the `Velocity` variable in your code does nothing, especially because you set it back to zero each frame.  You might just as well add directly to the `Position` property.

Answer (score 4):

No, velocity is independent from elapsed time, so:

```
if(right key pressed)
    Velocity.X = movementspeed;
else
    Velocity.X = 0;
...
Position += Velocity * deltaTime; // elapsed from last frame
```

Comment: Ok that's brilliant thanks for the help! Out of interest would me setting the velocity vector to zero accomplish what the else statements would?

Comment: Yeah, in this situation it's the same.

Comment: Be careful setting the Vector2 to Zero though if you want to maintain your Velocity on the Y axis. This is old but I came across this so I imagine others will.

Answer (score 0):

So first off: I don't know what kind of game you're making. If it's a top-down RPG, or anything where movement isn't really central to the mechanics, this approach is fine. If it's a Mario-like platformer, you may want to take the indirection one step further.

Try playing a Mario clone somewhere, and you'll notice he works up to full speed, and then takes a few frames to slow down when you let go of Right. This is accomplished through *acceleration*. Here's the pseudocode.

```
Update():
  if (right key is pressed):
    Acceleration = ACCELERATION_CONSTANT
  else if (Velocity != 0):
    // apply a braking force that will bring him back to 0. This should be in the
    // opposite direction he's travelling, but not dependent on the speed he's travelling.
    Acceleration = SMALL_BRAKING_CONSTANT * Vector2.Unit(-Velocity)
  Velocity += Acceleration * time
  Velocity = min(Velocity, VelocityMax) // prevent Mario from going too fast
  // at some point, you might have other influencers on the velocity, like collision 
  //detection. In basic games that's often done just by directly correcting position.
  Position += Velocity
  Velocity = 0
```